# Open "Class Explorer" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, class, explorer

Does anyone know where I can open the "Class Explorer" in Visual Studio 2010. I have been looking around for 1 hour :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class View or Class Explorer?

View -> Class View Ctrl+Shift+C ;)

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed looking for "Class View". The shorcut helped me to open it, because the Class View item does not appear neither in the View menu nor in "other windows" in the View menu.

Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

- Class View: <kbd>CTRL+W+C</kbd>
- Object Browser: <kbd>CTRL+W+J</kbd>

Look in the `View` menu.

Answer (score 0):

in first run of vs you may selected a setting profile that optimized for some thing which that doesn't need to have this option. you can reset setting profile to general from:

Tools -> Import And Export Settings... ;)